Limit of an Integral with a Floor Function
I'm looking to evaluate the following integral and would like to verify my answer:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \int_{0}^{n^2} \sqrt{\frac{n^2-\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor^2}{x}} \ \textrm{d}x$$
I've done the following so far. Firstly I applied the transformation $u = \sqrt{x}$ and the above integral transformed to
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \int_{0}^{n} \sqrt{n^2-\lfloor u\rfloor^2}\  \textrm{d}u$$
Then, I used the properties of floor functions to convert the integral to a sum of smaller integrals:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{k}^{k+1} \sqrt{n^2-k^2} \ \textrm{d}u = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{n^2-k^2}$$
At this point, I feel like I need to use the limit definition of definite integrals to convert this into an easier integral, but I'm having trouble with converting this into such a form. I have also checked WolframAlpha and it gives me a value of zero for the limit (assuming that regardless of the value of the sum, it'll be something of order $O(n)$, which zeroes out as the denominator is larger degree...)
Have I gotten the right answer? (I haven't been provided one.) If not, how do my steps look?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{n^2-k^2} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right)^2} = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} dx$$

That should be an answer.

@TheSilverDoe Thanks! I just briefly brain-farted there.

Didn’t you miss a factor $\color{red}{2}$ in second equation ?.  i.e. ${\rm d}u^{2}/{\rm d}u = \color{red}{2}u$.
